# How to request only for a web page header using netcat?

Tags: sed, netcat

I am not sure whether netcat has some command for requesting http header or should I use sed to filter the result? If sed is used in this case, is it so that I only have to extract everything before the first "<" occurs ?

Comment: I guess you have to get the whole page and then cut out all other than the header.  If you post what you get and what you like to have we can help out.

Comment: thanks, i found the solution, instead of using GET i used HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

The command line tool `curl` has the `-I` option which only gets the headers:

> -I/--head
>
> (HTTP/FTP/FILE) Fetch the HTTP-header only! HTTP-servers feature the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but the header of a document. When used on a FTP or FILE file, curl displays the file size and last modification time only.

Demo:

```
$ curl -I stackoverflow.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 503
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2013 21:06:15 GMT
```